# Load lightbox every 'x' amount of page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery Colorbox onLoad lightbox which works no problem.

This is the code so far, I was wondering how to make the lightbox appear every 5 page loads (for example). So as the user is browsing the site, every 5th page they visit the lightbox appears.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="res/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
        $.fn.colorbox({href:"xxxxx.jpg", open:true});  
        }, 1500);
          });
</script>
```

Thanks, any help is appreciated, even if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You'll need a way to keep a count of the page loads for a given session - either localStorage or a cookie - then simply read that value and compare it to whatever criteria.

Comment: Please convince whomever wants to do this to consider not making the Internet crappy.

Comment: @Will This is only for a demo and will not go live. If you're not going to say anything helpful, don't bother at all.

Comment: I'm trying to help the Internet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you would have to keep track of the page load count. Like Anthony suggested, you should keep it in a cookie.

I found two functions online to handle cookies: `cname` = cookie name, `cvalue` is what you save in the cookie, and `milliseconds` is for how long the cookie is valid;

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, milliseconds) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (milliseconds));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

So what you would want to do is every page load retrieve a cookie with the count and increase it:

```
var _pageloads = getCookie("PageLoadCount");
if(_pageloads=="")
{
_pageloads=0;
}

_pageloads +=1;
if(_pageloads ==5){
_pageloads =0;   //reset your counter

//pop up the lightbox
}

setCookie("PageLoadCount",_pageloads,1 * 60 * 1000);  //make cookie valid for one hour
```

Comment: Could you send me the link(s) to the sources of these so I can see them in slightly more context, I think I may be attacking it in the wrong way and may have an alternative in mind.

Comment: i dont remember, found those long ago on another stack overflow question. but generally what they do is simply set/retrieve cookie data, there is nothing else you could do with those

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thank you anyway, I'll see what I can do with these.